# Is there a function like min_active_rowversion for sequences?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have concurrent transactions getting values from a sequence. Is there a way to get the lowest active, non-committed value (and something like next value or NULL when nothing is active), like the function [min_active_rowversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-active-rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) does for rowversions?

It could also be for IDENTITY.

I'm trying to make something like rowversion for a memory-optimized table.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the transaction log looking for your table and changes to it.

Good place to start: [How to read the SQL Server Database Transaction Log](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3076/how-to-read-the-sql-server-database-transaction-log/)

Comment: Do you have an example?